# How to test F# option types with xUnit

Tags: f#, xunit.net

I want to unit test this bit of code using xUnit in F#. How do I handle the options?

From Scott Wlaschin's book: Domain Modeling Made Functional

```
type UnitQuantity = private UnitQuantity of int
// ^ private constructor

// define a module with the same name as the type
module UnitQuantity =
    /// Define a "smart constructor" for UnitQuantity
    /// int -> Result<UnitQuantity,string>
    let create qty =
        if qty < 1 then
            // failure
            Error "UnitQuantity can not be negative"
        else if qty > 1000 then
            // failure
            Error "UnitQuantity can not be more than 1000"
        else
            // success -- construct the return value
            Ok (UnitQuantity qty)
```

Test:

```
let ``Check UnitQuantity.create is one`` () =

    // ARRANGE
    let expected = 1

    // ACT
    //let unitQtyResult = UnitQuantity.create 1
    match UnitQuantity.create 1 with
    | Error msg -> 0
        //printfn "Failure, Message is %s" msg
    | Ok x -> 0
       // let innerValue = UnitQuantity.value actual

    // ASSERT
    //Assert.Equal(expected,actual)
```

I know the `ACT` is all wrong, that is where I am hung up. I do not understand F# options nor xUnit.net nor unit testing enough yet to Assert on the actual value from the function.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/SwensenSoftware/unquote - in general you can then say `test <@ None = actual @>` and/or use `match`es to break out the comparison rather than fiddling with `Assert.Equal` in F#

Comment: You may find it helpful if your are testing a lot of methods like this to add an method that checks for OK or Error. Its pretty easy and can make your test a lot cleaner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general rule of thumb with unit tests is that the Act section should be a single statement.

Everything that we want to check about the result is some form of assertion

So we want to assert whether the result is either an `Ok<UnitQuantity>` or an `Error<string>`.

This is where pattern matching allows us to test this very succintly

```
let ``Check UnitQuantity.create is one`` () =
    // ARRANGE
    let qty = 1 // The quantity we supply is one
    let expected = qty // We expect to get that value back

    // ACT
    let actual = UnitQuantity.create qty

    // ASSERT

    // Check if we have an Ok or an Error
    match actual with
      | Ok unitQuantity ->
        // If Ok, check the value is what we expect
        let innerValue = UnitQuantity.value unitQuantity
        Assert.Equal(innerValue, expected)

      // If Error raise an AssertException to fail the test
      | Error errorMessage ->
        let error = sprintf "Expected Ok, was Error(%s)." errorMessage
        Assert.True(false, error) // Force an assertion failure with our error message
```

Note the `UnitQuantity.value` method, it' a simple unwrap function you can add to the end of the `UnitQuantity` module that will give you back the `int` value so you can easily compare it

```
let value (UnitQuantity e) = e
```

If you wanted to test an `option` type, it would be very similar, using a match statement like so

```
match actual with
  | Some value ->
    // Do your assertions here
    ()
  | None ->
    // Do your assertions here
    ()
```

Comment: I get the error "FS0039 The value or constructor 'AssertException' is not defined." on the line
```raise (AssertException error)```
I changed to ```raise (SystemException error)``` and got it to compile, but am I missing something here?

Comment: I did manage to get the tests to run and pass. What am I missing about the AssertException? xUnit documentation and help files are almost non-existent and nothing for F#.

Comment: The `AssertException` actually comes from a different test suite I use in conjunction with Xunit called Expecto. It works very well with F# but apologies, I'll update the answer now to remove that and provide a better option

Comment: OK, that makes things better. Guess that also answers the question of is it possible to run both xUnit & Expecto at the same time. :)

Answer (score 5):

I'd probably compare the result directly rather than pattern matching. However, you can't create an `Ok` result for `Result<UnitQuantity, string>` because of the `private` constructor.

You can use the built-in [`Result.map`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/24c798bfcee5d6f91ae2c19888baeb9946744c3a/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/result.fs#L9) to map the `Ok` value of a result. Using `UnitQuantity.value` you can map from `Result<UnitQuantity, string>` to `Result<int, string>`. So this should work:

```ml
let expected = Ok 1

let actual = UnitQuantity.create 1 |> Result.map UnitQuantity.value

Assert.Equal(expected, actual)
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced with a similar problem, I decided I wasn't so concerned with checking the value itself, but with checking the behavior above and below the threshold. I decided to verify the result is `Ok` if the value is in range and an `Error` outside the range.

```
type UnitQuantity = private UnitQuantity of int

module UnitQuantity =

    let min = 1
    let max = 1000

    let create qty =
        if qty < min then
            Error $"UnitQuantity cannot be less than {min}"
        else if qty > max then
            Error $"UnitQuantity cannot be more than {max}"
        else
            Ok (UnitQuantity qty)

module Tests =

    let min = 1
    let max = 1000

    let shouldBeError = function
        | Error _ -> ()
        | _ -> failwith "is not error"

    let shouldBeOk = function
        | Ok _ -> ()
        | _ -> failwith "is not Ok"

    [<Fact>]
    let ``create unit qty at min`` () =
        UnitQuantity.create min |> shouldBeOk

    [<Fact>]
    let ``create unit qty below min`` () =
        UnitQuantity.create (min - 1) |> shouldBeError

    [<Fact>]
    let ``create unit qty at max`` () =
        UnitQuantity.create max |> shouldBeOk

    [<Fact>]
    let ``create unit qty above max`` () =
        UnitQuantity.create (max + 1) |> shouldBeError
```